# Sample Implementation for System.Web.Mvc.IView.Render()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, render

Is there a sample implementation for System.Web.Mvc.IView.Render() that I could use as a template?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. You should give a good name for your product (like Razor, KnightLight Dancer, NinjaSword) etc when you implemented the IView.

But you can implement when you need a simple text out (for printer) or etc you can do this. Please remember old fashioned ASP Response.Write when you use writer.